# Creating event handler with ImplementJavaInterface inside a package

Tags: packages, java, eventhandler

I am trying to make my Mathematica function to serve as an event handler for the events generated by a Java object.

Specifically, I have a Java object that connects as a client to a server that periodically pushes updates to all clients. I also have an observer object that calls it's `update` method whenever the client receives any updates.

My goal is to catch this updates inside Mathematica, and handle them with a Mathematica function

It appears that JLink has a way of doing this with `ImplementJavaInterface` command http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/ref/ImplementJavaInterface.html.
Here is how I've used it:

```
(* create a client that connects to localhost:3000 *)
client = JavaNew["me.kutrumbos.DdpClient", "localhost", MakeJavaObject[3000]];

(* create an observer that monitors client's events *)
observer = JavaNew["me.kutrumbos.examples.ObservableDdpClientObserver"];

(* create a variable that will be updated with data from incoming events *)
collections = {};

(* define event handler that updates collections variable with the new value *)
onCollectionUpdate[msg_] := collections = observer@getJSONObjectsList["coll"];

(* add event handler to the observer *)
observer@addMessageHandler[
   ImplementJavaInterface["me.kutrumbos.examples.MessageHandler", 
    "update" -> "onCollectionUpdate"]];

(* add observer to the client *)
client@addObserver[observer];

(* connect to the server *)
client@connect[];
```

When I run this inside a notebook, everything works. Every time an event occurs, `collections` variable gets updated with the data contained in the event.

However, when I put this code in the package, and expose `collections` by adding `collections::usage = "global var"` in the preamble of the package, the variable doesn't update, and the event handler doesn't even seem to run.

I tried inserting `MessageDialog["Event Handler alert"]` inside the event handler to see if the event handler is even called, and I am not getting any pop-up alerts when I generate new events on the server.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Without trying, my guess would be that once in a package, your symbol `onCollectionUpdate` becomes something like ``YourPackage`Private`onCollectionUpdate``, and this may be the source of trouble. So, you need to use now ``"update" -> "`YourPackage`Private`onCollectionUpdate"``, or whatever the long name for this symbol becomes inside a package.

Comment: Besides, you of course will need to load `JLink`, which I assumed you did in your package either using second argument of `BeginPackage`, or using ``Needs["JLink`"]`` in the implementation section.

Answer (score 4):

As Leonid suggested, I added the full path to the event handler, and it gets called now from inside the package:

```
observer@addMessageHandler[
   ImplementJavaInterface["me.kutrumbos.examples.MessageHandler", 
    "update" -> "Utils`Private`onCollectionUpdate"]];
```

Thanks, Leonid!