# Is it possible to create an event handler for changes in values of variables?

Tags: dynamic, eventhandler, networking

I am creating a networking application in Mathematica that runs a non-stop simulation, and periodically receives new information from the remote server that affects the simulation.

Whenever values of certain variables inside the simulation change, Mathematica needs to send an update with the values to the remote server.

Is there a way to catch an event in Mathematica that corresponds to the change in the value of a specific variable?

For example, assume that initially I have two variables: `a` and `b`, such that `a=1`, and `b=1`. Then, throughout the simulation one of the variables changes, while the second one remains the same: `a=2`, `b=1`. Is it possible to write an event handler that knows which variable has changed and what the new value is?

I've seen this discussion: [Triggering actions when a variable is set](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23977/triggering-actions-when-a-variable-is-set), that recommends using upvalues for `Set` and `SetDelayed`:
   `$var /: Set[$var, value_] := 
   Block[{$in = True}, Print["$var set to ", value];  $var = value] /; Not@TrueQ[$in]`

But this seems to not cover all possible cases when a variable might change, and requires defining UpValues for every variable.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not an answer in any way but just curious - how does your simulation communicate with the remote server?

Comment: @VincentTjeng, I have a Java object that periodically receives updates from the remote server through a websocket. When that happens it calls one of its methods, for which I created my own event handler in Mathematica using `ImplementJavaInterface[]`. This event handler basically assigns new values to variables that are used inside the simulation, and thus affects the simulation. I pasted some of the code in my previous question here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27330/creating-event-handler-with-implementjavainterface-inside-a-package

Comment: It might be possible by using by using java bean property change listeners. Please see the part with 'Using JavaBeans' http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromMathematica.html#15748 especially the part with  MathPropertyChangeListener and MathListener.

Comment: The better way is to use `Internal\`ValueChangeVeto` and `Internal\`AddHandler["VetoableValueChange", myVetoFunction]` as mentioned by Leonid in the other thread. Unfortunately, the operation of these is not fully understood, and it is not clear if these can be used with ownvalues. Regardless of that, this question is still a duplicate of the other one.