# Implement settable properties

Tags: programming, function-construction, evaluation, design-patterns, properties

I am looking for advice on implementing the following.  (It is possible that the answer is that it is simply not a good idea to do this.)

I would like to have an object similar to `FittedModel`.  Let's call its head `Obj`.

Like `FittedModel`, it will have properties, e.g.

```
properties = {42}; (* properties stored here for the sake of this toy example *)

Obj[id_]["Property"] := properties[[id]]
```

Now let's define `obj = Obj[1]` and evaluating `obj["Property"]` will yield `42`.

I am looking to make it possible to do `obj["Property"] = 137` to *set* this property.

Here's an attempt that doesn't quite work (let's ignore `SetDelayed` for now and stick to `Set`):

```
Obj /: (Obj[id_]["Property"] = value_) := setObjProperty[id, value]

setObjProperty[id_, value_] := properties[[id]] = value
```

Now `Obj[1]["Property"] = 137` will work as I want it to.

However, `obj["Property"] = 256` will not.  Instead of changing the property, it will associate the following definition with `Obj`:  `Obj[1]["Property"] = 256`.

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to implement this syntax for property setting in a reliable way?  I realize that this isn't exactly in the spirit of Mathematica objects being immutable.  In my case `Obj` represents a data structure implemented in C++ and `id` is a handle to it.

---

Note the following behaviour of `=` and `:=`:

[image]

The head of the expression to be set is evaluated by `Set` (or `SetDelayed`).

---

`Graph` has settable properties which are handled through `SetProperty`, `PropertyValue`, etc.  I find this syntax very tedious, so I was looking for something simpler.

For my application having mutable state seems very natural, and I think it's not worth avoiding.  I have a simulation that has a complex internal state, *not fully exposed to Mathematica*.  The simulation can be stopped and resumed.  Parameters can be adjusted when the simulation is stopped.

I think (I may be wrong) that in order to work only with immutable objects, in the natural Mathematica way, it would be necessary to expose the full simulation state to Mathematica and to store it as a pure Mathematica expression (instead of data on the C side).  I would then store the *full* state as an `Association`, and have a function that runs the simulation and returns a new `Association` (simulation state), along with data collected during the simulation process.  Associations would also give me this easy property-setting syntax for free.

However, exposing the full state may not be worth all the extra work.

Comment: Of course all this is not necessary at all to get the work done, it would just be nice to have :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well that's a hairy one.  I like it though, as it forced me to think about aspects of evaluation that I am normally oblivious to.  Unfortunately that thinking didn't lead to any great insights.  My only idea so far is to interrupt evaluation and mess with the Stack as Leonid did for [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-you-set-attributes-on-subvalues/545#545)
I have little experience in this area and I am sure to make a number of blunders before I figure it out, but nevertheless here is a first attempt as a proof of concept.

Starting with your own definitions:

```
properties = {42};

Obj[id_]["Property"] := properties[[id]]

Obj /: (Obj[id_]["Property"] = value_) := setObjProperty[id, value]

setObjProperty[id_, value_] := properties[[id]] = value
```

And adding mine:

```
_Obj :=
  Block[{Obj},
    Obj /: (Obj[id_]["Property"] = value_) := setObjProperty[id, value];
    With[{set = 
      Cases[Stack[_], HoldForm[L_ = R_]?(FreeQ[#, Obj] &) :> ((# = R) &@L), 1, 1]},
      Return[set[[1]], Set] /; set =!= {}
    ]
  ]
```

This surely adds significant and possibly unacceptable overhead.  Nevertheless:

```
obj = Obj[1];

obj["Property"] = 256;

properties
```

> ```
> {256}
> ```

I make no claim that this is in any way robust.  Perhaps something better will come to me later.

Comment: Congrats on hitting 100k!

Answer (score 4):

How about the old [Gayley-Villegas trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656/2427624)?

```
Obj /: (lhs_ = Obj[id_]) := 
  Block[{$inSet = True},
 lhs /: (lhs["Property"] = value_) := setObjProperty[id, value];
 lhs /: Unset[lhs] := ClearAll[lhs];
 lhs = Obj[id]
  ] /; ! TrueQ[$inSet]
```

Then we get the following behaviour:

```
obj = Obj[1];
UpValues[obj]
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[obj["Property"] = value$_] :> setObjProperty[1, value$]}
> ```

```
obj["Property"] = 42;
properties
```

> ```
> {42}
> ```

It's a bit dirty though, but it might just be what you're after.

Comment: Interesting trick.  But what if I do `obj =.` next?  The up-value stays.

Comment: @Szabolcs Well then we should also overload `Unset` in the `Block` ... let's see if I can update the answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs This is basically the same idea as what I used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47659/how-to-implement-the-observer-design-pattern/47664#47664) (although not using VG). Didn't suggest it here precisely because of the hanging `UpValues` problem. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the new `MutationHandler` code is designed for this sort of thing. Here is one implementation:

```
ClearAll[ObjHandler]
SetAttributes[ObjHandler, HoldAll];

ObjHandler[Set[m_Symbol?objQ[key_String], rhs_]] := (
    Extract[
        m,
        1,
        Function[Null, AssociateTo[#, key->rhs], HoldAll]
    ];
    rhs
)

Language`SetMutationHandler[Obj, ObjHandler]

ClearAll[Obj]
SetAttributes[Obj, HoldFirst]

objQ[m_] := MatchQ[m, _Obj]

(* property extraction *)
Obj /: Obj[a_][key_] := a[key]
Obj /: Obj[a_]["Properties"] := a

(* formatting *)
MakeBoxes[Obj[a_Symbol], StandardForm] ^:= With[{id = Lookup[a, "ID", "<>"]},
    RowBox[{"Obj", "[", MakeBoxes[id], "]"}]
]

(* object creation *)
makeObject[id_] := Module[{z},
    z = <|"ID"->id|>;
    Obj[z]
]
```

Make an object with id 1:

```
obj = makeObject[1]
```

> Obj[1]

Set key "property1" to 23, and "property2" to "Real":

```
obj["property1"] = 23
obj["propery2"] = "Real"
```

> 23
>
> "Real"

Find properties of `obj`:

```
obj["Properties"]
```

> <|"ID" -> 1, "property1" -> 23, "propery2" -> "Real"|>

"property1":

```
obj["property1"]
```

> 23

[`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) of `obj`:

```
obj //InputForm
```

> Obj[z$136716]

Definition of `z$133176`:

```
z$133176
```

> <|"ID" -> 1, "property1" -> 23, "propery2" -> "Real"|>

While it is possible to create an auxiliary variable to store definitions, it is probably more robust just to store the information in the object itself. So I recommend an alternate approach:

```
ClearAll[ObjHandler]
SetAttributes[ObjHandler, HoldAll];

ObjHandler[Set[m_Symbol?objQ[key_String], rhs_]] := With[
    {new = Association[First @ m, key -> rhs]},
    Set[m, Obj[new]];
    rhs
]

Language`SetMutationHandler[Obj, ObjHandler]

ClearAll[Obj]

objQ[m_] := MatchQ[m, _Obj]

(* property extraction *)
Obj /: Obj[a_][key_] := a[key]
Obj /: Obj[a_]["Properties"] := a

(* formatting *)
MakeBoxes[Obj[a_Association], StandardForm] ^:= With[{id = Lookup[a, "ID", "<>"]},
    RowBox[{"Obj", "[", MakeBoxes[id], "]"}]
]
```

Create an object:

```
obj = Obj[<|"ID"->2|>]
obj //InputForm
```

> Obj[2]
>
> Obj[<|"ID" -> 2|>]

Assign values:

```
obj["p1"] = x + 1
obj["p2"] = y
```

> 1 + x
>
> y

Check properties:

```
obj["Properties"]
obj["p1"]
```

> <|"ID" -> 2, "p1" -> 1 + x, "p2" -> y|>
>
> 1 + x

Compare [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm) and [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) of `obj`

```
obj
obj //InputForm
```

> Obj[2]
>
> Obj[<|"ID" -> 2, "p1" -> 1 + x, "p2" -> y|>]

The nice thing about this approach is that all of the property information is embedded in the object, and so it is still there even after restarting the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** Looks like I accidentally dismissed everything in the post below the horizontal line confusing it to comments, and tried to answered a more general question than needed. Too bad.

To clarify: the idea represented below is to have [still immutable] objects with pointers (in the form of symbols) to their properties inside the objects themselves, which makes it possible to extract pointers from expression anytime if needed.

For ease of use, however, I propose a way to define the pointers' structure unambiguously by the object structure; and instead of just placing pointers inside `Hold`, wrap them in `Dynamic` for a cleaner representation in the FrontEnd. In effect, properties become usual settable expressions.

---

> It is possible that the answer is that it is simply not a good idea to do this.

It's probably true.

If you want to refer to object with properties as

```
Obj[id_]["Property"]
```

and want to `Set`

```
obj["Property"] = 137
```

then why not just

```
Obj[_]["Property"] := 137
```

whenever you need it?

From my modest but somewhat extensive experience, the only real reason one might need a flexible general complex mutable structure is for bulding complex graphical interfaces with minimal amount of boilerplate. This is also probably *the only* moment when one needs something like “object id”.

What I ended up with was looking like this:

(Note: `Unevaluated` and `Hold`s are probably not needed)

```
setProperty // ClearAll

SetAttributes[setProperty, HoldFirst];

Options@setProperty = {"HeadsHistory" -> HoldComplete[]};

setProperty[head_[most___, outerProperty_@inner__, rest___]
, HoldComplete[outerProperty_, innerProperties__]
, value_
, OptionsPattern[]] :=
head[most
   , setProperty[outerProperty@inner
     , HoldComplete@innerProperties
     , value
     , "HeadsHistory" ->
       Append["HeadsHistory" // OptionValue
       , Unevaluated@head]]
   , rest]

setProperty[head_[most___, mostInnerProperty_Symbol@Dynamic@expr_, rest___]
, HoldComplete@mostInnerProperty_Symbol
, value_
, OptionsPattern[]] :=
( expr = value;
  head[most, mostInnerProperty@Dynamic@expr, rest] )

setProperty[head_[most___, mostInnerProperty_Symbol[], rest___]
, HoldComplete@mostInnerProperty_Symbol
, value_
, "HeadsHistory" -> HoldComplete@heads__] :=
( mostInnerProperty@Compose[head, heads] = value;
  head[most
     , mostInnerProperty @
       Dynamic@mostInnerProperty@Compose[head, heads]
     , rest] )
```

How this works:

```
setProperty[
  "car"[1][
    "engine"[power[], type[]]
  , "driver"[name[], mood[]]]
, HoldComplete["engine", power]
, 250]

car[1][engine[power[500], type[]], driver[name[], mood[]]]
```

Of course, engine's power is only displayed as 500, by means of `Dynamic`. The real value is stored in a transparently structured expression:

```
setProperty[
  "car"[1][
    "engine"[power[], type[]]
  , "driver"[name[], mood[]]]
, HoldComplete["engine", power]
, 500] // FullForm

"car"[1][
  "engine"[power[Dynamic[power[Compose["engine", "car"[1]]]]], type[]]
, "driver"[name[], mood[]]]
```

Note that we've reset the value to 500.

Call it:

```
power@"engine"@"car"@1
500
```

A drawback: you have to use symbols for innermost keys. However, `setProperty` returns a complete object, with all its properties in it, and it is displayed nicely.

I haven't yet thought about possible applications for 2nd, 3rd, … arguments of `Dynamic` here.

When one can't afford a symbol for particular property's name, one may stick to strings, and use a universal symbolic head, like `Property` (Which would make references slightly more cumbersome, of course.), in which case the `Dynamic` wrapper probably becomes obsolete, unless one uses the technique to build complex interactive GUIs.

Comment: Regarding why I need an object ID, and why this is non-negotiable: the ID is a handle to a data structure implemented in C, not in Mathematica, and I'm also using [managed library expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#353220453).  `Obj[1]` and `Obj[2]` refer to different data structures.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh, I didn't notice that in the initial post. :-( My answer seems to be completely useless then.

Comment: Well, it's not useless, it's interesting.  I just can't apply it to my problem :-)  In the end I'm using a syntax like `ObjSet[obj, property -> value]` to change the state of `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I tend to deal with this problem is by using `MessageName` instead of `SubValues` and overloading it. By attaching a single or small set of `UpValue` overrides to `MessageName` we get a visually appeal way to do OOP that also doesn't add vastly too much overhead. It is, of course, never terribly advisable to mess with built-ins but I think given the specialized nature of `MessageName` we are likely safe (and in fact I've used this extensively in various projects of mine without issue).

To do this we'll do a Villegas-Gayley:

```
isObj[s_] := 
  MatchQ[OwnValues[
    s], {Verbatim[HoldPattern][HoldPattern[s]] :> _Obj}];
isObj~SetAttributes~HoldFirst;
Unprotect@MessageName;
MessageName[s_, prop : Except["usage"]] /; ! 
    TrueQ@$messageNameOverride :=
  If[isObj@s,
   getattr[s, prop],
   Block[{$messageNameOverride = True}, MessageName[s, prop]]
   ];
MessageName /: 
  HoldPattern[Set[MessageName[s_, prop : Except["usage"]], v_]] /; ! 
    TrueQ@$messageNameOverride :=
  If[isObj@s,
   setattr[s, prop, v],
   Block[{$messageNameOverride = True}, MessageName[s, prop]]
   ];
Protect@MessageName;
```

where the `isObj` is just a safe `MatchQ[s,_Obj]` and `getattr` and `setattr` are get / set functions of your choosing.

And what you get is this:

```
In[176]:= a = Obj[1]

Out[176]= Obj[1]

In[177]:= a::b

Out[177]= getattr[Obj[1], "b"]

In[178]:= a::b = 2

Out[178]= setattr[Obj[1], "b", 2]
```

A great thing about this is that since `MessageName` converts the second argument to a string implicitly one can make private attributes that can't be accessed via this mechanism using `Key` or something.

This does add significant overhead to `MessageName`:

```
In[179]:= Do[a::b, 10000] // AbsoluteTiming // First

Out[179]= 0.056259

In[180]:= Unprotect@MessageName; Clear@MessageName; Protect@MessageName;

In[182]:= Do[a::b, 10000] // AbsoluteTiming // First

Out[182]= 0.002118
```

But I don't think `MessageName` is called often enough for this to be entirely disqualifying.